# Laravel and jQuery Sortable Returns Null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-5

I've search for about an hour or two to find an answer to my problem of why jQuery returns null using toArray/serialize. I find alot of answers here in SO but still don't work for me.

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sortable">
            @foreach($items as $item)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="bg-gray ui-sortable-handle" id="item-{{ $item->id }}">Item {{ $item->id }}</div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        update: function(event, ui) {

            var items = $(this).sortable('serialize', {
                attribute: "id",
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '/change/position',
                data: items,
                type: 'POST'
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

**ItemsController**

```
public function movePosition()
{
    dd(request()->input('items'));
}
```

Checking the Chrome Dev Tool result is `null`.